# 301 redirects to wrong url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i have following Problem.

i set up this in my htaccess:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect 301 /blog/2012 https://www.new-url.com/wissen/blog/archive/
```

But when i enter https://www.new-url.com/blog/2012 i came up to https://www.new-url.com/wissen/blog/2012/

I've also tried this one:

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/2012/?$ https://www.new-url.com/wissen/blog/archive/ [L,R=301]
```

I always end up here: https://www.new-url.com/wissen/blog/2012/

but i want to end up here : /wissen/blog/archive

Comment: 1. `Redirect` directive has nothing to do with the rewrite engine, 2. `Redirect` does prefix matching only, that it appends the rest of the path to the target URL is explicitly described in the documentation. And 3., when configured in .htaccess context, the path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at this point already.

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you do not need mod_rewrite here since mod_alias handles your this nicely.

Try it like this:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/2012 /wissen/blog/archive
```